# SQL Stored procedures syntax error , Adding Multiple Parameters in SSRS from a Stored Procedure one Returns Blank

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, reporting-services, syntax-error, parameter-passing

I want to be able to add another parameter to my SSRS report that'll search using CustNum from my SQL stored procedure. When I added the @custnum INT parameter into the SQL stored procedure it wouldn't pass through & return any results. I received this error msg : ::

**Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure GPA, Line 254 [Batch Start Line 9] Incorrect syntax near 'END'.**

Any idea how to get this parameter added to so that I could pull the info via customer number, along with the days past due parameter.

Here's -- Dataset1 (from the stored procedure):

```html
USE [database]
GO

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[GPA]    Script Date: 6/23/2017 4:22:49 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GPA] 

( 
@DaysPD INT,
@CustNum INT
)

AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
 
 -- exec GPA 45
    SELECT DISTINCT inv.InvoiceId AS InvoiceID
        ,ent.EnterpriseName AS Enterprise
        ,inv.customerNumber AS CustNum
        ,cust.CompanyName AS CustName
        ,inv.InvoiceNum AS InvNum
        ,inv.TotalAmountDue AS Amount
        ,inv.DocDate AS DocDate
        ,inv.DueDate AS DueDate
        ,datediff(day, GETDATE(), inv.DueDate) * - 1 AS DaysPastDue
        ,CASE 
            WHEN (
                    SELECT datediff(day, inv.DueDate, GETDATE())
                    ) >= (
                    SELECT [from]
                    FROM cs_agingbucket
                    WHERE agingdetailid = 1
                        AND [from] <> 0
                    )
                AND (
                    SELECT datediff(day, inv.DueDate, GETDATE())
                    ) <= (
                    SELECT [to]
                    FROM cs_agingbucket
                    WHERE agingdetailid = 1
                        --AND [to] <> 0
                    )
                THEN (
                        SELECT label
                        FROM CS_AgingBucket
                        WHERE AgingDetailId = 1
                        )
            WHEN (
                    SELECT datediff(day, inv.DueDate, GETDATE())
                    ) >= (
                    SELECT [from]
                    FROM cs_agingbucket
                    WHERE agingdetailid = 2
                        AND [from] <> 0
                    )
                AND (
                    SELECT datediff(day, inv.DueDate, GETDATE())
                    ) <= (
                    SELECT [to]
                    FROM cs_agingbucket
                    WHERE agingdetailid = 2
                        --AND [to] <> 0
                    )
                THEN (
                        SELECT label
                        FROM CS_AgingBucket
                        WHERE AgingDetailId = 2
                        )
            WHEN (
                    SELECT datediff(day, inv.DueDate, GETDATE())
                    ) >= (
                    SELECT [from]
                    FROM cs_agingbucket
                    WHERE agingdetailid = 3
                        AND [from] <> 0
                    )
                AND (
                    SELECT datediff(day, inv.DueDate, GETDATE())
                    ) <= (
                    SELECT [to]
                    FROM cs_agingbucket
                    WHERE agingdetailid = 3
                        --AND [to] <> 0
                    )
                THEN (
                        SELECT label
                        FROM CS_AgingBucket
                        WHERE AgingDetailId = 3
                        )
            WHEN (
                    SELECT datediff(day, inv.DueDate, GETDATE())
                    ) >= (
                    SELECT [from]
                    FROM cs_agingbucket
                    WHERE agingdetailid = 4
                        AND [from] <> 0
                    )
                AND (
                    SELECT datediff(day, inv.DueDate, GETDATE())
                    ) <= (
                    SELECT [to]
                    FROM cs_agingbucket
                    WHERE agingdetailid = 4
                        --AND [to] <> 0
                    )
                THEN (
                        SELECT label
                        FROM CS_AgingBucket
                        WHERE AgingDetailId = 4
                        )
            WHEN (
                    SELECT datediff(day, inv.DueDate, GETDATE())
                    ) >= (
                    SELECT [from]
                    FROM cs_agingbucket
                    WHERE agingdetailid = 5
                        AND [from] <> 0
                    )
                AND (
                    SELECT datediff(day, inv.DueDate, GETDATE())
                    ) <= (
                    SELECT [to]
                    FROM cs_agingbucket
                    WHERE agingdetailid = 5
                        --AND [to] <> 0
                    )
                THEN (
                        SELECT label
                        FROM CS_AgingBucket
                        WHERE AgingDetailId = 5
                        )
            WHEN (
                    SELECT datediff(day, inv.DueDate, GETDATE())
                    ) >= (
                    SELECT [from]
                    FROM cs_agingbucket
                    WHERE agingdetailid = 6
                        AND [from] <> 0
                    )
                AND (
                    SELECT datediff(day, inv.DueDate, GETDATE())
                    ) <= (
                    SELECT [to]
                    FROM cs_agingbucket
                    WHERE agingdetailid = 6
                        --AND [to] <> 0
                    )
                THEN (
                        SELECT label
                        FROM CS_AgingBucket
                        WHERE AgingDetailId = 6
                        )
            WHEN (
                    SELECT datediff(day, inv.DueDate, GETDATE())
                    ) >= (
                    SELECT [from]
                    FROM cs_agingbucket
                    WHERE agingdetailid = 7
                        AND [from] <> 0
                    )
                AND (
                    SELECT datediff(day, inv.DueDate, GETDATE())
                    ) <= (
                    SELECT [to]
                    FROM cs_agingbucket
                    WHERE agingdetailid = 7
                        --AND [to] <> 0
                    )
                THEN (
                        SELECT label
                        FROM CS_AgingBucket
                        WHERE AgingDetailId = 7
                        )
            WHEN (
                    SELECT datediff(day, inv.DueDate, GETDATE())
                    ) >= (
                    SELECT [from]
                    FROM cs_agingbucket
                    WHERE agingdetailid = 8
                        AND [from] <> 0
                    )
                AND (
                    SELECT datediff(day, inv.DueDate, GETDATE())
                    ) <= (
                    SELECT [to]
                    FROM cs_agingbucket
                    WHERE agingdetailid = 8
                        --AND [to] <> 0
                    )
                THEN (
                        SELECT label
                        FROM CS_AgingBucket
                        WHERE AgingDetailId = 8
                        )
            WHEN (
                    SELECT datediff(day, inv.DueDate, GETDATE())
                    ) >= (
                    SELECT [from]
                    FROM cs_agingbucket
                    WHERE agingdetailid = 9
                        AND [from] <> 0
                    )
                AND (
                    SELECT datediff(day, inv.DueDate, GETDATE())
                    ) <= (
                    SELECT [to]
                    FROM cs_agingbucket
                    WHERE agingdetailid = 9
                        --AND [to] <> 0
                    )
                THEN (
                        SELECT label
                        FROM CS_AgingBucket
                        WHERE AgingDetailId = 9
                        )
            ELSE (
                    SELECT label
                    FROM CS_AgingBucket
                    WHERE AgingDetailId = 10
                    )
            END Aging
        ,stat.NAME [Status]
        ,invact.lastactname AS LastAct
        ,invact.WorkDate AS LastActDate
        ,invact.nextactname AS NextAct
        ,invact.NextWorkDate AS NextActDate
        ,us.FirstName + ' ' + us.LastName AS UserID
        ,isnull(cur.Symbol, '$') AS CurSymbol
    FROM CS_Invoice inv
    JOIN CS_Customer cust ON cust.CustomerId = inv.CustomerId
    JOIN CS_Enterprise ent ON inv.EnterpriseId = ent.EnterpriseId
    LEFT JOIN CS_Account acct ON cust.CustomerId = acct.CustomerId
    JOIN CS_User us ON acct.UserId = us.UserId
    JOIN CS_Status stat ON stat.StatusId = inv.InvstatusId
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT maxwork.invoiceid
            ,WORK.ActionTakenId
            ,lastact.NAME lastactname
            ,WORK.NextActionId
            ,nextact.NAME nextactname
            ,WORK.WorkDate
            ,WORK.NextWorkDate
        FROM CS_WorkAccount WORK
        LEFT JOIN CS_SecurityPrivilege lastact ON WORK.ActionTakenId = lastact.SecurityPrivilegeId
        LEFT JOIN CS_SecurityPrivilege nextact ON WORK.NextActionId = nextact.SecurityPrivilegeId
        JOIN (
            SELECT workinv.InvoiceId
                ,max(workinv.workaccountid) maxid
            FROM CS_WorkAccountInvoice workinv
            GROUP BY workinv.InvoiceId
            ) maxwork ON WORK.WorkAccountId = maxwork.maxid
        ) invact ON inv.invoiceid = invact.invoiceid
    LEFT JOIN CS_Currency cur ON cur.CurrencyId = inv.CurrencyId
    WHERE inv.TotalAmountDue <> 0
 AND datediff(day, GETDATE(), inv.DueDate) * - 1 >= @DaysPD
 IF ((@CustNum != 0 AND @CustNum = @CustNum)
    
END


GO
```

Any idea how to get the @CustNum parameter to work in SSRS.

Comment: Is the last line correct? (IF (@CustNum != 0 AND @CustNum = @CustNum))?

Comment: Probably not. I wanted to add if the custnum is input as '0' return 'all'. & the customer number imputed = the except number imputed

Comment: e.g. if you input custnum = 10 you only want results for 10 customers? If so, which order do you want them, as I don't see an ORDER BY?

Comment: I could have sworn I commented on this earlier... ? Anyway, The last line should read `AND (ISNULL(@CustNum,0) = 0 OR inv.customerNumber = @CustNum))

Comment: @AlanSchofield Thanks! that worked perfectly!! You're a lifesaver.

Comment: If I wanted to only pull >=0 from DaysPastDue & omit anything with a negative int for the ssrs report. Do I have to update the statement, if so how so that the report would see it